# Непонятный баг в тестах junit

Tags: kotlin, юнит-тесты, junit

У меня есть тест

```
 @Test
fun testVictorineProgressAndropointSuccess() = runTest {
    val userInfo = UserInfoEntity(
        id = 1,
        name = "John Doe",
        image = null, 
        userLanguage = "English",
        phoneBrand = "Samsung",
        token = "userToken",
        andropointCount = 0,
        lastOnlineDate = "2023-08-09",
        strikeModeDay = 5,
        lastOpenCourse = 123,
        lastOpenTheme = 456
    )

    val isSuccessStates = mutableListOf<ErrorEnum>()

    userLogicRepo.insertUserInfoLocal(userInfo)
    andropointUseCase.victorineProgressAndropoint(
        correctAnswer = 5,
        isSuccess = { isSuccessStates.add(it) }
    )
    assertEquals(isSuccessStates.size, 1)
    assertEquals(isSuccessStates[0], ErrorEnum.SUCCESS)

    assertEquals(
        userLogicRepo.getUserInfoLocal().value?.andropointCount,
        VICTORINE_REMUNERATION
    )

}
```

Код, который я тестирую :

```
@SuppressLint("SuspiciousIndentation")
suspend fun victorineProgressAndropoint(correctAnswer:Int, isSuccess:((ErrorEnum)->Unit)){
    val andropointCount = VICTORINE_REMUNERATION
        try {
            updateAndropointPlus(andropointCount=andropointCount)
            isSuccess.invoke(ErrorEnum.SUCCESS)
        }catch (e:IOException){

            if(checkSubscibe()){
                isSuccess.invoke(ErrorEnum.OFFLINEMODE)
            }
            if(checkBuyCourse()){
                isSuccess.invoke(ErrorEnum.OFFLINEMODE)
            }
            isSuccess.invoke(ErrorEnum.NOTNETWORK)
        }catch (e:HttpException){
            crashUseCase.sendCrash(exception = e.message(), className = this.toString())
            isSuccess.invoke(ErrorEnum.ERROR)

        }catch (e:Exception){
            crashUseCase.sendCrash(exception = e.message ?: "unknown error", className = this.toString())
            isSuccess.invoke(ErrorEnum.UNKNOWNERROR)

        }catch (e: TimeoutException){
            crashUseCase.sendCrash(exception = e.message ?: "timeout error", className = this.toString())

            isSuccess.invoke(ErrorEnum.TIMEOUTERROR)
        }catch (e:NullPointerException){
            crashUseCase.sendCrash(exception = e.message ?: "nullpoint exception", className = this.toString())
        }
}
```

В этом коде вызывается данная функция:

```
 private suspend fun updateAndropointPlus(andropointCount:Int) {
    val userInfoLocal = userLogicRepo.getUserInfoLocal().value
    userInfoLocal?.let { myInfo ->
        updateUserInfoUseCase.updateUserInfo(andropointCount = myInfo.andropointCount?.plus(andropointCount))
    }
}
```

В ней идет вызов функции :

```
 suspend fun updateUserInfo(name:String?=null,andropointCount:Int?=null,image:Bitmap?=null,strikeModeDay:Int?=null,lastOnlineDate:String?=null,lang:String?=null,phoneName:String?=null){
    val userInfoLocal = userLogicRepo.getUserInfoLocal().value

    val updateUserEntity = UserInfoEntity(
        id = userInfoLocal?.id,
        name = name ?: userInfoLocal?.name ?: "",
        andropointCount = andropointCount ?: userInfoLocal?.andropointCount ?: 0,
        image = image ?: userInfoLocal?.image,
        token = userInfoLocal?.token ?: "",
        lastOnlineDate = lastOnlineDate ?: userInfoLocal?.lastOnlineDate ?: "",
        strikeModeDay = strikeModeDay ?: userInfoLocal?.strikeModeDay ?: 0,
        lastOpenTheme = userInfoLocal?.lastOpenTheme ?: 0,
        lastOpenCourse = userInfoLocal?.lastOpenCourse ?: 0,
        userLanguage = lang ?: userInfoLocal?.userLanguage,
        phoneBrand = phoneName ?: userInfoLocal?.phoneBrand ?: "Xiaomi"
    )
    Log.d("MyLog",updateUserEntity.andropointCount.toString())
    userLogicRepo.updateUserInfoLocal(updateUserEntity)
    if (phoneName.isNullOrEmpty()){
        val userUpdateBackend = UserSignInModel(
            token = userInfoLocal?.token ?: "",
            name = name ?: userInfoLocal?.name,
            image = image ?: userInfoLocal?.image,
            andropointCount = andropointCount ?: userInfoLocal?.andropointCount,
            lastOnlineDate = lastOnlineDate ?: userInfoLocal?.lastOnlineDate,
            strikeModeDay = strikeModeDay ?: userInfoLocal?.strikeModeDay,
            lastCourseNumber = userInfoLocal?.lastOpenCourse,
            lastThemeNumber = userInfoLocal?.lastOpenTheme
        )
        userLogicRepo.updateUserInfo(userUpdateBackend)
    }
}
```

В ней меняется количество andropoint и после просиходит:

```
 userLogicRepo.updateUserInfoLocal(updateUserEntity)
```

Фейковая реализация репозитория :

```
class FakeUserLogicRepo : UserLogicRepo {
    
    private val fakeUserInfo = MutableLiveData<UserInfoEntity>()
    override suspend fun insertUserInfoLocal(userInfoEntity: UserInfoEntity) {
        fakeUserInfo.postValue(userInfoEntity)
    }

    override suspend fun updateUserInfoLocal(userInfoEntity: UserInfoEntity) {
        fakeUserInfo.postValue(userInfoEntity)
    }

    override fun getUserInfoLocal(): LiveData<UserInfoEntity> {
        return fakeUserInfo
    }
```

После вызова victorineProgressAndropoint должен происходить апдейт и в проверке:

```
  const val VICTORINE_REMUNERATION = 45
 assertEquals(userLogicRepo.getUserInfoLocal().value?.andropointCount,VICTORINE_REMUNERATION)
```

Должно приходить число 45, и тест должен быть успешно выполнен, но приходит значение переменной userInfo. То есть почему-то апдейта не произошло, хотя в логах в updateUserInfo приходит значение 45. Я также пробовал сделать апдейт в самом тесте:

```
@Test
    fun testVictorineProgressAndropointSuccess() = runTest {
        val userInfo = UserInfoEntity(
            id = 1,
            name = "John Doe",
            image = null, // Set your Bitmap here
            userLanguage = "English",
            phoneBrand = "Samsung",
            token = "userToken",
            andropointCount = 0,
            lastOnlineDate = "2023-08-09",
            strikeModeDay = 5,
            lastOpenCourse = 123,
            lastOpenTheme = 456
        )
        val userInfo2 = UserInfoEntity(
            id = 2,
            name = "John Doe",
            image = null, // Set your Bitmap here
            userLanguage = "English",
            phoneBrand = "Samsung",
            token = "tfy",
            andropointCount = 45,
            lastOnlineDate = "2023-08-09",
            strikeModeDay = 5,
            lastOpenCourse = 123,
            lastOpenTheme = 456
        )
        val isSuccessStates = mutableListOf<ErrorEnum>()

        userLogicRepo.insertUserInfoLocal(userInfo)
        andropointUseCase.victorineProgressAndropoint(
            correctAnswer = 5,
            isSuccess = { isSuccessStates.add(it) }
        )
        assertEquals(isSuccessStates.size, 1)
        assertEquals(isSuccessStates[0], ErrorEnum.SUCCESS)
        userLogicRepo.updateUserInfoLocal(userInfo2)

        assertEquals(
            userLogicRepo.getUserInfoLocal().value?.andropointCount,
            VICTORINE_REMUNERATION
        )
```

И тут уже тест успешно срабатывет.
И мне непонятно, почему тест не работает, когда я использую victorineProgressAndropoint

Comment: Подозреваю что в тесте и в коде userLogicRepo -- разные репы.